# OneDrive/Office365:: Get all users for a tenant

Tags: sharepoint, office365, onedrive

I am looking for a way to fetch all users for my Office365 business solution.
I am using Graph API to get all the users. Is there any other way? I have been trying this as well

```
https://{tenantName}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/siteusers
```

Is this ok? Also, Graph API doesn't indicate that a user has active OneDrive. So rephrasing my question. How do I get all OneDrive users for an Office365 tenant?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Syed - only just saw this.  When you get users though Graph API, you can see their assigned licenses under the [assignedPlans](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn168178.aspx) complex type.  It'll look a bit like:

```
  "assignedPlans": [
    {
      "assignedTimestamp": "2014-12-09T23:12:18Z",
      "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
      "service": "MultiFactorService",
      "servicePlanId": "8a256a2b-b617-496d-b51b-e76466e88db0"
    },
    {
      "assignedTimestamp": "2014-12-09T23:12:18Z",
      "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
      "service": "AADPremiumService",
      "servicePlanId": "41781fb2-bc02-4b7c-bd55-b576c07bb09d"
    },
    {
      "assignedTimestamp": "2013-04-25T23:00:00Z",
      "capabilityStatus": "Deleted",
      "service": "SharePoint",
      "servicePlanId": "e95bec33-7c88-4a70-8e19-b10bd9d0c014"
    },
    {
      "assignedTimestamp": "2013-04-25T23:00:00Z",
      "capabilityStatus": "Deleted",
      "service": "SharePoint",
      "servicePlanId": "5dbe027f-2339-4123-9542-606e4d348a72"
    }
  ]
```

So if it contains a service called "SharePoint" with capabilityStatus of enabled, then this user has been assigned OneDrive for business.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, so I just checked, that indeed is correct, however there is one disconnect. The problem is that I have users (couple of them for diff tenants) which are valid users on OneDrive (when i check through the admin centers - office365 settings) but these users haven't logged in to their OneDrive ever(meaning their OneDrive site gives a 404 even though they are valid existing users). Graph API call sends these users along with other active users and "assignedPlans" have Sharepoint enabled for these inactive users. I can't figure out other than accessing their Site, as to who is actually active!